# Is it possible to ignore a list item using the Skip method of the LINQ then apply skip on the list without losing that item?

Tags: c#, linq, pagination

I want to implement paging on a list of data. The list has some fake items in itself as flag items for doing some specific work on the data. A simplified version of what I have done is as below:

```
List<Model> list = _myServiceContract.MyServiceMethod(MySearchModel);
pagedData = list.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
```

But my problem with this way is that the fake items will be counted in the `Skip` and `Take` methods of the *Linq*.

I want to know if it is possible to ignore those fake items in the `Skip` method then apply `Skip` on the list, including fake items by some changes in the `Take` method for example or something similar.

Edit: The first list is ordered before doing paging and those fake items are in ordered places also. You should know the order of the list is important for me.

Comment: You can put a `Where` before the `Skip` to filter out the "fake" items first.

Comment: No @juharr. Where condition will lose that fake data from result

Comment: Can you `TakeWhile(fake).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize)`? An example set of data would be helpful, I am not really sure what it looks like from your description.

Comment: Something like `.SkipWhile(x => (x.IsFake ? toSkip : toSkip--) > 0).TakeWhile(x => (x.IsFake ? toTake : toTake--) > 0)`.  You just have to calculate `toSkip` and `toTake` upfront and allow the query to mutate those values as you inspect if an item is fake or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest I don't like what you're doing. I'd consider modelling your data better in future. However, here's a couple of extension methods that'll get the job done...

(I've essentially modified the original implementations of `Skip` and `Take` from https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs)

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> SkipAndInclude<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));

    using (IEnumerator<TSource> e = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        while (count > 0 && e.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!predicate(e.Current)) count--;
        }
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            while (e.MoveNext()) yield return e.Current;
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<TSource> TakeAndInclude<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int count, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));

    if (count > 0)
    {
        foreach (TSource element in source)
        {
            yield return element;
            if (!predicate(element)) count--;
            if (count == 0) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage...

```
pagedData = list.SkipAndInclude((page - 1) * pageSize, x => x.Fake).TakeAndInclude(pageSize, x => x.Fake);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about iterating over the list manually to find the index of fake items, then adding them in later. Something like this:

```
var fakeItems = new Dictionary<int, Model>();
var unpaged = MyService.MyServiceMethod(MySearchModel);

for (var i = 0; i < unpaged.Count; i++)
{
    if (unpaged[i].IsFake)
        fakeItems.Add(i, unpaged[i]);
}

var paged = unpaged.Where(x => !x.IsFake)
    .Skip((page - 1) * pageSize)
    .Take(pageSize);

foreach (var item in fakeItems){
{
    if((pageSize * (page - 1)) <= item.Key && item.Key < (pageSize * page))
        paged.Insert(item.Key, item.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a where to ignore those items like this:

```
List<Model> list = MyService.MyServiceMethod(MySearchModel);
pagedData = list.Where(x => !x.Fake).Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
```

Do not forget to **Order** your items. Otherwise you could have problems when paging (skip & take).

Comment: I tried this solution before. It will lose the fake items from result.

Comment: I don't totally understand where do you want to have those items and how many of the fake items you should have in each page. I seems to me that maybe you are trying to do something with one List that you should do with two different methods? Please give me more information about your requirement so I can think of a better solution.